# How to delete a key from the dictionary using Python function

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary

How to delete a key from the dictionary using Python function. Sample code I wrote but throwing null dictionary

```
myDict = {'A': [('Yes!', '8'), ('Ok!', '0')], 'B': [('No!', '2')]}

class my_dict(dict):
    def remove_key(self,myD, key):
        del myD[key]
dict_obj = my_dict()
dict_obj.remove_key(myDict,'A')
print(dict_obj)
```

Desired output :

```
{'B': [('No!', '2')]}
```

I can use the dictionary comprehension below but not the case.

```
{k: v for k, v in myDict.items() if 'A' not in k}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `dict.pop(key)` or call `del dict[key]` directly?

Comment: Please explain in more detail in words what you are trying to do. Your `remove_key` is a method, and is accepting two dictionaries: `self` and `myD`. What do you want to happen to each of them, and what do you want returned? Right now, you are deleting the key from `myD`, and then returning `self` (which was, and remains, an empty dictionary).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this (edited after realizing there is a class method):

```
# the variable to change
myDict = {'A': [('Yes!', '8'), ('Ok!', '0')], 'B': [('No!', '2')]}

class my_dict(dict):
    def remove_key(self,myD, key):
        myD.pop(key) # <-- change the parameter passed
# a separate instance of the class (separate from var to change)
dict_obj = my_dict() #<-- this instance has nothing/ empty dictionary
dict_obj.remove_key(myDict,'A') 
print(dict_obj)  #<-- you will get an empty dictionary here
print(myDict) #<-- myDict has changed
```

Explanation:

del just delete the local variable. To remove something from a dictionary, use pop method.

Edited: del removes local variable. When you give a dictionary[key], it removes the element from dictionary. When you give a list[index], it removes the element from the list. However, its readability is not good. Therefore, following "explicit is better than implicit", I suggest to use pop. <-- yes, this is an opinion.

The main point here is that OP is confusing between dictionary parameter and inheriting a dictionary as an object. That's why I highlight them in the comments. Peace.

Comment: why we need to explicitly give dict_obj = dict_obj.remove_key(myDict,'A')

Comment: `del` for a plain name only removes the variable binding. But `del myD[key]` will delete the key (and its associated value) from the dictionary, and is more efficient than calling `pop`; you only call `pop` if you need to remove the key/value pair *and* return the value (or if you pass a second argument, to remove the binding without raising an exception if the key does not exist). This doesn't fix the OP's code in any way; the changed code is functionally equivalent, just slightly less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Python's function allows you to directly eliminate the key and with it the value it possesses, it turns out to be in my thinking the most optimal way because it is a function proper to language

```
    myDict = {'A': [('Yes!', '8'), ('Ok!', '0')], 'B': [('No!', '2')]}
    del myDict['A']
    print(myDict)
```

Comment: Can you add the result in a code block rather than an image please?

Comment: Of course, my friend, thank you very much for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    del myDict["A"]# input your key here
except KeyError:
    print("Key 'A' not found")#gives informative feedback if key not in dict
```